# Как сократить код?

Tags: javascript

Есть несколько объектов `newa`, `newp` и `newv`.

Как сократить этот код:

```
if(...){
 newa.playlist[t].num = $('.tagEditor .num').val();
 newa.playlist[t].name = $('.tagEditor .name').val();
 newa.playlist[t].artist = $('.tagEditor .artist').val();
 newa.playlist[t].album = $('.tagEditor .album').val();
 newa.playlist[t].date = $('.tagEditor .date').val();
}else if(...){
 newp.playlist[t].num = $('.tagEditor .num').val();
 newp.playlist[t].name = $('.tagEditor .name').val();
 newp.playlist[t].artist = $('.tagEditor .artist').val();
 newp.playlist[t].album = $('.tagEditor .album').val();
 newp.playlist[t].date = $('.tagEditor .date').val();
}else if(...){
 newv.playlist[t].num = $('.tagEditor .num').val();
 newv.playlist[t].name = $('.tagEditor .name').val();
 newv.playlist[t].artist = $('.tagEditor .artist').val();
 newv.playlist[t].album = $('.tagEditor .album').val();
 newv.playlist[t].date = $('.tagEditor .date').val();
}
```

и не писать много раз `new?.playlist[t]`?

Comment: В ответах примеры для одного элемента, а у вас их несколько (newa, newp или newv), в зависимости от условия выполняются действия для одного из них. Никто не написал про то, как можно оптимизировать и это:

    var currentObject = null;
    if (...) {
        currentObject = newa;
    } else if (...) {
        currentObject = newp;
    } else if (...) {
        currentObject = newv;
    }
    if (currentObject != null) {
        perfomAction(currentObject);
    }


где perfomAction(...) - функция обработки из ответов.

Будет полезно, если где-то ниже надо будет использовать измененный объект.

Comment: Мб создать обычную функцию инициализации?

Comment: @0xFFh, это мне? Мой комментарий относился к случаю "если где-то ниже надо будет использовать измененный объект".

Т.е. мы используем currentObject, а не объект, зависящий от условий.

Если ТС, то тов. @RubaXa указал пример такой функции.

Если в отдельную функцию вынести совет тов. @Indev, то его ответ также подойдет. Единственное, я бы на всякий случай добавил проверку на hasOwnProperty.

Answer (score 5):

```
var fields = ['num', 'name', 'artist', 'album', 'date'], 
    obj = newv;

if(...) obj = newa;
if(...) obj = newp;

for(var i in fields) {
  obj.playlist[t][fields[i]] = $('.tagEditor .' + fields[i]).val();
}
```

Comment: Эээ... А вы уверены, что это сработает? может всё же

    obj.playlist[t][fields[i]]

Comment: @VladD, поправил. Спасибо.

Comment: Огромная просьба - не используйте вы for in цикл для массивов, это плохо, конечно, не eval, но тоже, мягко говоря, не хорошо, к тому-же в этом нет ничего сложного.

Если, вдруг, вы были не вкурсе, мало ли, то [Ссылка по теме](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/why-is-using-for-in-with-array-iteration-such-a-bad-idea)

Comment: AlexWindHope, для ассоциативных массивов(объектов) вполне можно использовать.

Comment: @AlexWindHope, спасибо за замечание. Оно, конечно, не абсолют, но в голове держать способность JS возвращать неожиданные данные при использовании "for... in" определенно следует.

Answer (score 3):

Простой перебор?

```
for (var i in newa.playlist[t])
{
newa.playlist[t][i] = $('.tagEditor .' + i).val(); 
}
```

И так для всех.

Answer (score 2):

http://jsfiddle.net/rrAmg/ — пример работы

```
$.extractMetaData = (function (names/**array*/){
    return function (target/**jQuery|String*/){
        var data = {};
        $.each(names, function (i, name) {
            data[name] = $('.' + name, target).val();
        });
        return data;
    };
})('num name artist album date'.split(' '));

// Usage
newa.playlist[t] = $.extractMetaData('.tagEditor');
```

Answer (score 1):

Отвечаю только на поставленный вопрос

> не писать много раз new?.playlist[t]

сократить можно с помощью ключевого слова [`with`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/with):

```
if(...){
    with( newa.playlist[t]){
        num = $('.tagEditor .num').val();
        name = $('.tagEditor .name').val();
        artist = $('.tagEditor .artist').val();
        album = $('.tagEditor .album').val();
        date = $('.tagEditor .date').val();
    }
}else if(...){
    with( newp.playlist[t]){
    ...
```

Но использовать `with` не рекомендуется, и это не работает в strict mode. Рекомендуемая [там же](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/with) альтернатива — временная переменная, примерно, как и пишут в других ответах.

```
var X;
if(...){
    X = newa.playlist[t];
    X.num = $('.tagEditor .num').val();
    X.name = $('.tagEditor .name').val();
    X.artist = $('.tagEditor .artist').val();
    X.album = $('.tagEditor .album').val();
    X.date = $('.tagEditor .date').val();
}else if(...){
    X = newp.playlist[t];
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 function xx(zz)
 {
   zz.num = $('.tagEditor .num').val();
   zz.name = $('.tagEditor .name').val();
   zz.artist = $('.tagEditor .artist').val();
   zz.album = $('.tagEditor .album').val();
   zz.date = $('.tagEditor .date').val();
 }

 if (..) { 
   xx(newa.playlist[t]);
 }
 else if (..)
 {
   xx(newv.playlist[t]);
 }
 else
   xx(newp.playlist[t]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const props = [
    'num',
    'name',
    'artist',
    'album',
    'date'
]

function getval(element, t){
    for (const prop of props){
        element.playlist[t][prop] = $(`.tagEditor ${prop}`).val()
    }
}

if(...){
    getval(newa)
}else if(...){
    getval(newp)
}else if(...){
    getval(newv)
}
```